# stable sorting in O(n log (log n))

Tags: sorting

For a given array of N real numbers, every number has a key of his own, but the keys are not necessarily different. It is known that we have k different keys.

I need to find a stable sorting algorithm in O(N log (log N)) complexity when k=O(log N),
I can use extra space of O(N)?

I tried everything and I can't think of anything.

Comment: All the things you tried, can you update your question with one of those attempts?

Comment: Isn't it awkward to specify the complexity first and find the algorithm later? This more looks like a exam question: "Which stable sort algorithm offers complexity O(n log(log n))?" Here is a list of common sorting algorithms with their complexity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm claims Han's and Thorup's algorithms have your required complexity.

Answer (score 3):

As Tilman Vogel points out, there are algorithms which can theoretically run in Θ(n log(log n)) complexity by imposing specific limitations on the input data. It seems they'd be unlikely to provide great benefit in most practical applications, and probably why I've never seen an implementation, but if they fit your use-case, I'd be very curious to see if those algorithms benchmark faster.

This is an excerpt from Steven S. Skiena's *The Algorithm Design Manual* explaining why it's impossible to come up with a general-purpose Θ(n log(log n)) sort algorithm:

> We have seen several sorting algorithms that run in worst-case O(n log n) time, but none of which is linear. To sort n items certainly requires looking at all of them, so any sorting algorithm must be Ω(n) in the worst case. Can we close this remaining Θ(log n) gap?
>
> The answer is no. An Ω(n log n) lower bound can be shown by observing that any sorting algorithm must behave differently during execution on each of the distinct n! permutations of n keys. The outcome of each pairwise comparison governs the run-time behavior of any comparison-based sorting algorithm. We can think of the set of all possible executions of such an algorithm as a tree with n! leaves. The minimum height tree corresponds to the fastest possible algorithm, and it happens that lg(n!) = Θ(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this bound, we have to think on trees, specifically on binary search trees. Exists a class of binary search trees, that have some extra information in the node, like parent, left child, right child, and color ... yes I'm talking about red black trees. The time complexity to insert one node in a RB tree is O(log n), n is the number of nodes of the tree. The basic idea is traverse the array, and insert every element in the RB tree, but with one constraint, if we detect a duplicated element, don't insert!!!, just count!. How to do that? easy, just add a field "count" in the node, and every time you find a duplicated element just augment the counter, but don't insert as a new node. Doing this, the RB tree only will have O(k) elements, i.e., O(log n) for our example. So the complexity to insert one node in a RB tree is O(log (log n)). Once we insert all the elements in the RB tree, the time complexity will be O(n log (log n)). The next step is traverse the tree in-order!!, and duplicated every element such that the counter is. Doing this we have the sorted array (RB trees are binary search trees), and because the time complexity to traverse in-order is O(n), the overall time complexity will be  O(n log (log n)).

Comment: Interesting idea!
I wonder if it'll also apply to other self-balancing BSTs and not just RB? (e.g. AVL)

Answer (score 0):

You guys are thinking of the 'traditional' sorting algorithms (bubble, merge, quick etc), when the original algorithm he described is basically a description of BucketSort or RadixSort. These don't fall under the Ω(nlogn) restriction as they do not perform binary comparisons, but comparisons according to the number of items to be sorted!

I can only guess that a form of Radixsort for a polylogarithmic number of keys or values of the n items to be sorted, can have the desired complexity. However I am not 100% sure as I have not tested it nor proven it.

Answer (score 0):

We are dealing with comparison model, not the word ram model. As we know, we can't go through the lower bound `n log h`, where `n` is the input size and `h` is the number of elements in the container. In sorting algorithms, we can achieve the upper bound by any balanced binary search tree, including **RBT** and **AVL** and priority queue(Cartesian tree sort).

In this case, the key is that the size of the chosen container can't be larger than `h = k = log n`(we say `h = n` in general because of universality). Essentially, raul_zevahc gets this idea, we just need to slightly modify the solution to achieve **stable** sort. Instead of counting, which is actually counting the number of elements in a set, we maintain a **queue**(first in, first out) for each node. Whenever a node is traversed, we pop out all elements of that node.

---

For unstable sorting algorithm, we can always change it to the stable one with the cost of linear time preprocessing.

Comment: you've tagged your answer as code which results in the wrong formatting - could you edit your submission and remove the "`" at the front and back?